# Including the same blocks in several pages in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

On my website, blog posts appear in multiple places across the site. I want to create a template like `blog_posts.html` that given the list of blog posts (as an argument to `render`) creates the block with these posts, formatted and processed.

There are several disconnected pages to which I want to display `blog_posts`. Thus, I can not say that `blog_posts` extend any of them. I wonder if there is a way to insert whatever template processed to arbitrary page? If yes, how to I pass variables (which may be instances of the classes) to the blog_posts template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either render `blog_posts.html` to string and pass it as a variable to the other template:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
blog_posts = get_template('/path/to/blog_posts.htm')
somevar = blog_posts.render({'foo': 'foo', 'bar': 'baz'})
```

then place `{{ somevar }}` in the other template -  or just `{% include '/path/to/blog_posts.html' %}` in the other; the included template will have access to all variables passed to the 'parent' one.

Comment: I have not found it to be the case that "the included template will have access to all variables passed to the 'parent' one." It doesn't seem to work for forms for example.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider using template tags. Something like the inclusion tag should serve you well (see here for docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

You could use the takes_context argument to pass the data. So that any page you want to use the inclusion tag on you could already populate that page with a context variable of 'data' in the view then this function would pickup on it like this

```
@register.inclusion_tag('/path/to/blog_posts.html', takes_context=True)
def blog_posts(context):
    return {
        'blog_posts': context['data'],
    }
```

Then usage in you html file you want to pull blog posts into

```
{% blog_posts %}
```

Usage from any views. make sure you set data anywhere you want to also use the template tag

```
def example_view(request):
    context = {'data': Blog.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

Another option is to explicitly pass it in as an argument like this

```
@register.inclusion_tag('/path/to/blog_posts.html')
    def blog_posts(context, data):
        return {
            'blog_posts': data,
        }
```

Then usage

```
{% blog_posts data %}
```

and of course your blog_posts.html file that is used in the inclusion tag would do something like looping over the data

```
<div>
    {% for post in blog_posts %}
    <p>{{ post.name}}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```